# How do I import column with values like '661-' into MySql?

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a csv file from a legacy dbase dbf file.  The data contains a few columns which have number values with hyphens.  Like this '661-'.  I am trying to import the csv into MySql using 'Import External Data' in MySql Yog.  The issue is, the columns that have values with hyphens are getting imported as decimals resulting in '-661.0000'.

This is odd as the column format in the csv (via MS Excel) is 'general' not  'number' and I am trying to import these values into varchar fields.  Seems MySql is ignoring the settings.

Has anyone faced something like this or have any suggestions on how I can get the data in as a string not a decimal?

Thanks

Comment: how  does it look in csv and what is a type of the field in DB

Comment: Columns in a CSV have no inherent type - Excel does a best guess at the data type from the contents of the first few rows or by whatever the user sets - when saved it is not possible to save the data type in CSV format. In your CSV file are the fields like 666- quoted - which would indicate strings rather than numeric values? What type is the MySQL table column that it being imported into?

Comment: The MySql Col is a varchar.  In the csv this is the first row (after header) of data 100-.  The value is not quoted tho.  Maybe that's the issue.  Perhaps MySql is seeing it as a numeric.  I will check the raw csv.

Comment: Ah.  The values in csv are not quoted.  I'll see if I can change that...

Comment: Ok got it.  See edit above for answer.  Thanks for the input folks!

Comment: @tenz please don't answer as an edit to the bottom of your question. Rather, put it in an answer below (a self-answer). Thx.

Comment: Done, thank for the advice Drew.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER - sorry to be answering my own question but I did solve it with some group input.

The file needs to be saved with all fields (that you want to be treated as string) in quotes. MS Excel DOES NOT seem to have an option for this. Apache Open Office does. Open the file in AOO and save as text.csv. From there you can edit the filters and set all cells to be in quotes. Problem solved.